# How to exclude a package.json from a git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have three branches in the repository.

```
master
slave 1
slave 2
```

there is one `package.json` file. It should be different in each of the branches. But if I run the `git merge master` command. These two branches merge into one. How to exclude `package.json` from merging branches so that each branch has its own version?

add:

I have a sequence

git checkout slave 1 && git merge -Xtheirs --no-edit master  && git push && git checkout master

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: I don't think he is looking for that. He *wants* these files to be there yet not be merged. But again, it depends on him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to tell git to avoid merging changes on a file. You can ask to check out the file from HEAD before finishing the merge:

```
git merge other-branch --no-commit
git checkout HEAD -- package.json # get the file back
git commit -m "Now we finish the merge"
```

Comment: I am add info in question. What i want

Comment: `--theirs` is only about conflicting stuff... not even _files_ but conflicting pieces of code. Again: there is no way to tell git to keep a file from merging.... you can get the file back before finishing it up, as I explained.